# Hibernate insertion issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have two entities:PS_PUBLICATION and PS_PUBLICATION_PROPERTIES

PS_PUBLICATION has a list of PS_PUBLICATION_PROPERTIES

In the logs the inserts look fine but at the end i got an error

```
insert into PS_PUBLICATION (CREATION_DATE, message, FK_SUBJECTAREA_ID, status, subject, UPDATE_DATE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 

binding '2011-07-06 10:36:43' to parameter: 1 

binding 'dc8ca7f0-9d8d-11e0-89b1-00212834363a' to parameter: 3 

binding 'PUBLISHED' to parameter: 4 

binding 'publication 2' to parameter: 5 

binding '2011-07-06 10:36:43' to parameter: 6 

binding '13d6df10-a7ab-11e0-ac48-00212834ce10' to parameter: 7 

insert into PS_PUBLICATION_PROPERTIES (PROP_VALUE, PROP_KEY, FK_PUBLICATION_ID) values (?, ?, ?) 

binding 'close' to parameter: 1 

binding 'CALL-CATEGORY-OPEN' to parameter: 2 

binding '13d6df10-a7ab-11e0-ac48-00212834ce10' to parameter: 3 

06 Jul 2011 10:36:43,680  WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
06 Jul 2011 10:36:43,681 ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - ORA-02291: integrity constraint (EPF7_NOTIF.SYS_C0018903) violated - parent key not found

WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter:100
    - SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000 06 Jul 2011 10:36:43,690 ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener:324
    - Could not synchronize database state with session org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update   
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
```

In the inserts everythign look fine !

Any idea what might cause this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException`:

> Implementation of JDBCException indicating that the requested DML operation resulted in a violation of a defined integrity constraint.

Double check if the data you want to insert does not violate database constraints. It looks like the database isn't happy with the values.

(If you catch that exception, call `ex.getConstraintName()`, that should give more details.)

Didn't notice, the the constraint name was in the question ;) You'll find that constraint's definition in the database. Ask your oracle instance and it will tell you, which table and thus which insert causes trouble.

---

> **Error:**
>       ORA-02291: integrity constraint  violated - parent key not found
>
> **Cause:**
>       You tried to reference a table using a unique or primary key, but the columns that you listed did not match the primary key, or a primary key does not exist for this table.

You provide two UUIDs as foreign keys - one of them is not a primary key in some other table. Or at least - not recognized as a primary key by oracle.

[This link may help](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora02291.php).

Comment: The constraint name is in the error message: EPF7_NOTIF.SYS_C0018903

Comment: is there in the stack integrity constraint (EPF7_NOTIF.SYS_C0018903) violated - parent key not found but everythign is set if you look in the inserts :(

Comment: @JB Nizet - Ah, found it, didn't scroll the window ;)

Comment: What is this EPF7_NOTIF.SYS_C0018903 constraint? Are you sure it's a constraint between those two entities? Maybe PROP_KEY or PROP_VALUE is a foreign key to some reference table?

Comment: Thanks for all you hint...it lead me to the right problem...copy paste from another constraint...:(